# Data Deduplication on VMWare workstation

Tags: caching, duplicates, vmware, vmware-workstation

i am using VMWare workstation pro 12.5.0 on windows machine(Host). I am running 2 VMs(ubuntu 14.04) on VMWare. I want to use data deduplication on these VMs. VMWare support TPS which is disabled by default due to which inter-VM dedpulication is disabled but intra-VM deduplication is enable. Can anyone help me in fixing this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

TPS, or transparent page sharing, is a feature that's only available for RAM and is generally only used during periods of contention.

Workstation doesn't have the ability to do disk based deduplication, if that's the question. And intra-VM dedup wouldn't have the ability to perform any deduplication between the two separate VMs. That's a guest-OS level action.

Comment: Thank you Kyle for the reply .  i think for dedup i need to use VMWare Esxi .Am i right ?  Does KVM support Dedup , if yes then i can use KVM for my work .

Comment: ESXi doesn't do any kind of dedup, that would be a job for the underlying storage. I believe KVM operates in the same way. The hypervisors just present storage for you to use. Dedup, compression, etc. are all features of the storage technology you're choosing to use.